# Stream music from computer to phone whilst still playing on computer

Tags: iphone, stream

I have searched the internet for awhile for a solution to this, and cant seem to find anything on my own. Alright.

Is there any software that will allow me to stream music to my phone from VLC. I specifically would like my phone to be plugged into my main stereo system in the other room, while having my computer stereo running as well. There seems to be plenty of solutions for streaming the data to your phone, but browsing all seems to be done on the phone itself. I have an iPhone 5.

Sorry if this issue isn't clear. Ill elaborate if necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

VLC has a streaming feature for files, just go to Media -> Stream -> Add (add your files) -> Click Stream in the bottom right corner -> Click Next -> Select destination as HTTP -> Click Add -> Select an unused port -> enter a path if you want -> Next -> Uncheck Activate transcoding -> Next -> Stream. Now on your iPhone download VLC for iOS and open up a media stream like this http:// + your ip + : + port + path e.g. `http://192.168.1.100:8808/music`.
You're done.